# C# matrices aleatorias

Tags: c#, matrices, random

Estoy intentando crear una matriz aleatoria, donde solo haya un numero "2", varios números "1" al azar y el resto rellenado con "0", el caso es que, al mostrar la matriz, cumple su trabajo, pero si solicito mostrar nuevamente la matriz, aparece otra matriz totalmente aleatoria, he probado muchas cosas, y no entiendo por que pasa si el proceso aleatorio es llamado una sola vez, en la función mostrar no se modifica en ningún momento los valores.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    const int casillas=5;
    public static void mostrar(int[,] T)
    {
        int x=0, y=0;

        for(y=0; y < casillas; y++)
        {
            Console.Write("\n|");
            for(x=0; x < casillas; x++) 
            {
                Console.Write(T[x,y] + "|");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        int x,y;
        int[,] tablero=new int[casillas,casillas];
        Random random = new Random();
           for(y=0; y < casillas; y++)
           {
                for(x=0; x < casillas; x++)
                {
                    if(random.Next(0,10) == 0)
                    {
                        tablero[x,y]=1;
                    }
                    else 
                       tablero[x,y]=0;
                }
            }
            Retry:
            x=random.Next(0,casillas);
            y=random.Next(0,casillas);

            if(tablero[x,y] == 0)
            {
                tablero[x,y]=2;
            }
            else goto Retry;
        while(true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            mostrar(tablero);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de cómo llamas a la función mostrar?

Comment: Al final hay un "while(true)", este esta como metodo de prueba y ahi esta la llamada a mostrar

Comment: Si la pruebas en una función separada, no en un while, tienes el mismo resultado?

Comment: Sip, ocurre lo mismo, otra matriz aleatoria diferente.
Tengo que probarlo en otro compilador, como no estoy en mi pc, uso uno de navegador, puede que simplemente sea error de impresion o algo por el estilo

Comment: Si yo ejecuto tu código no consigo reproducir lo que comentas.  Aqui es donde lo estoy ejecutando https://repl.it/repls/MundaneFrillyRobots

Comment: efectivamente, tema zanjado, el problema está en este compilador
https://dotnetfiddle.net/